# Does this question deserve to be in the Review Audit List?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

Is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31192894/programmatically-detect-primary-and-foreign-keys-for-two-tables-fluent-nhibernat) a Good Question and qualified to be in Review Audit list?

This question does not:

1. Specify which RDBMS or Database is in use, so Proper database tags are missing
2. Show any search effort
3. Include already tried code

I [failed on this review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/8923726) in First Posts Review queue. I think, this question does not deserve to be in Review Audit List. Its in Review Audit list, based on UP-VOTES, but it should be based on content also.

Comment: How that question got 13 upvotes is beyond me.

Comment: that's also confuses me..

Comment: Well, that's certainly not a good question. At a minimum, it should be closed as "unclear", and the OP prompted to add the missing DBS.

Comment: Yes..I agree on that...but What for I benned for review fail...

Comment: I've personally been seeing huge spikes in voting for questions with bounties lately, often without any relationship to their quality. Something about their visibility has changed in a way that's driving a ton of votes to anything with a bounty. It's led to a number of odd audit cases like this.

Comment: @BradLarson Something to do with the new nav perhaps? I guess you guys have no way to trace a vote to a referrer?

Comment: @ Brad Larson:- I think we have to modify criteria to select question for Review Audits, its not only UPVOTEs matter but content also. I does not know what the actual criteria is now a days?

Comment: And how do you want to evaluate content, if not by using the evaluations of users?

Comment: as you see evaluations of users is not right always, and we have example question. Here 13 upvotes, but question is quite poor

Comment: @HaveNoDisplayName If you do get banned by a bad audit then you should be able to bring it up here and mod should be able to lift it.  that said the hopefully there are not enough "bad" audits out there that you would be served with enough to get a review ban.

Comment: Sadly stating that users are not always right does not help this issue. The only way this site can evaluate content is on that content being evaluated by the users. If the users up-vote something there is no way to determine for what. As Brad basically said, it is likely that a bounty was placed and the up-votes come from people wanting the question to be noticed. In reality this question should have been voted to close WAY before a bounty could have been placed. Obviously it was missed.

Comment: @ Cayce K:- I agreed with you Maximum times(or say always) users are rights and do upvotes...but at the same time our review audits failed due to this type of poor questions

Comment: @ NathanOliver:- ban for 2 days and that I served already...Actually I was in fear before asking the question here and raise the issue, because this question has upvotes and already many questions asked on meta like mine

Comment: I would say this has to be looked at 1 other way... Apparently nHibernate (or what ever that is exactly) is the key to the question and the one user who noticed that in of itself was able to provide a decent enough answer to it. In a bad backwards way one could argue that the audit itself is right based on the provided answers. Also.. [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10583/289907) seems to cover a few things. One being `A question with a bounty cannot be closed.` So people may have just moved on if it had a bounty when they saw it..

Comment: @Cayce K:- then it is big issue, if  "Questions containing a bounty cannot be closed", so it means system should not display close button, if bounty is there

Comment: Don't disagree there..

Comment: The real issue here really does seem to be one that's been a request for years, and that should really be added, of having a more formal "request for audit review" process than making people post public questions on meta about individual audits - something where you click a button indicating "I don't agree with this", can specify why, then it gets sent to a mod. Mod agrees with you: it's like it never happened, and the question is removed from the audit list. Mod disagrees: it moves you closer to a review ban. (This isn't a new suggestion, it's a suggestion from like years ago.)

Comment: @neminem:- Agreed on that...but the point bring on board is quite big, and also a big feature request

Comment: @neminem That sounds like a lot of extra work for the Moderators.

Comment: Since bounty questions can't be flagged and are getting up-votes when they shouldn't, can questions with bounties just be excluded as possible audits?

Comment: @BSMP:- You can not say that all bounty questions are not deserve to be in Audit list, only some questions are not. and that list, I think, should be quite small

Comment: _You can not say that all bounty questions are not deserve to be in Audit list_ Why not? What problem does it cause if bounty questions are never audits?

Comment: Follow-up: [Should I be concerned about Featured Questions inflating votes?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300560/should-i-be-concerned-about-featured-questions-inflating-votes)

Comment: I specified my database and codes that i have, why do you continuing to down vote?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I do not understand why I failed this audit](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303795/i-do-not-understand-why-i-failed-this-audit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Brad Larson mentioned in comment that it seems upvotes comes to this question lately when OP add bounty regardless the question's quality. Then after upvotes this question becomes eligible to display in review audit list, and that's the starting of some unusual review audits where question have no quality.

> I've personally been seeing huge spikes in voting for questions with
>   bounties lately, often without any relationship to their quality.
>   Something about their visibility has changed in a way that's driving a
>   ton of votes to anything with a bounty. It's led to a number of odd
>   audit cases like this. –  Brad Larson♦ Jul 26 at 22:05

So just down-vote and close the question is the only way to get rid of this type of review audits right now.

Comment: The question have been closed, but the OP have improved its question... Is it fair ?

Comment: When question closed, at that time question was in low quality. If question improved, then it is eligible to be in REOPEN review queue, where community vote to reopen, if improved, it same as vote for close. Here is nothing fair or unfair