# Failed a review audit, even though the post was of low quality

Tags: discussion, review-audits

I was reviewing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/9000444) on SO and I downvoted it as it was of low quality but to my surprise I was told I had failed.

I don't consider this question a good quality post. There is no example of what has been tried already by the user or what issues they have come against to date. Am I wrong!?

[image: review screen shot]

Comment: You are imho perfectly right. It is however a question which the community has deemed good, and that's why you "failed". I think we simply have a question here that a fair amount of users have too, and therefore gave it an upvote. It's however not a great question.

Comment: @Bart and that is why I often open the question in another tab to make the "correct" review. I've been surprised before, and so now I let the SO community review for me.

Comment: Please don't do so @Trobbins. If you were suspended from reviewing for what were actually valid reviews, contact a mod/CM. But don't forego on good reviews just so you don't hit a snag like this.

Comment: What queue was this in?  Could you link to the review?

Comment: @Bart IMO, the audits are in place so that we aren't rushing with current submissions (at least..the ones I currently have access to :) ). If an old question is still living, I don't consider myself experienced enough to have a say, and I go with the status quo (is the answer on hold, upvoted, downvoted, etc).

If I happen to vehemently disagree with a review, I will make the "correct" review to pass the audit, and then flag the question in the other tab. My goal when in a queue is to help moderate and subsequently pass the audits.

Comment: You can always skip @Trobbins.

Comment: Of course, @Bart. Though, are you implying I should skip the review and flag in the other tab? Passing an audit doesn't necessarily mean I agree with it.

Comment: @Bart - In the [meta question where this method of passing audits is discussed](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287670/review-audits-exploitable-able-to-see-real-review-stats-before-voting-on-the-re/287852#287852), the consensus was that this is OK because audits are meant to stop robo-reviewers, not people willing to look at the question to make sure they're making the right call.

Comment: I also want to make it clear that my comments above are under the implication that audit questions are almost always obvious. I'm not opening -all- questions in new tabs. Just those that require passing an audit.

Comment: @Bart, like Trobbins, I'm suspended from reviewing for 7 days after failing this review audit question.

Comment: @NathanOliver, Heres the review question, http://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/9000444

Comment: You said "I don't consider myself experienced enough to have a say, and I go with the status quo" @Trobbins. I say that the simple option there is to skip. If you don't know, you don't know. But that's a discussion for another time/place perhaps. Not these comment. ;)

Comment: Looks like this same deal as here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300236/does-this-question-deserve-to-be-in-the-review-audit-list#comment226022_300236 . Voting hugely inflated by the presence of a bounty. This is starting to become a trend.

Comment: @BradLarson - I think your comment should be the answer to that question and this one as well. Would it be possible to exclude bounty questions as potential audits? I'll make a feature request if that seems reasonable.

Comment: @BradLarson - I believe that the bounty activity is the result of bounties being included in the needs answer query with the new interface.

Comment: @ Brad Larson:- what a co-incidence, both question have originally 13 upvotes