# I do not understand why I failed this audit

Tags: discussion, support, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

Whilst reviewing over on Stack Overflow I got the [following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32026895/how-to-get-source-code-from-installed-app-on-the-android-phone)

> **How to get source code from installed app on the android phone?**
>
> I mistakenly formated my WD hard disk.And I lost all my project work.
> I can't return it any recovery app. Please suggest good data recovery
> app or help me find My Android application last version on my android
> phone. How can I get source code from the phone?

I felt that this was off topic, and asking to recommend a tool *("Please suggest good data recovery app")* and furthermore has nothing to do with programming.

So I flagged it as off-topic, but was faced with the blue-screen-of-death-equivalent **STOP! Look and Listen,** – i.e. I failed the audit

Any ideas?

---

[Original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32026895/how-to-get-source-code-from-installed-app-on-the-android-phone)

[My review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/9334848)

Comment: very related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300560/should-i-be-concerned-about-featured-questions-inflating-votes

Comment: The idea is that many users (and SO itself as a system) don't care much about the rules of the site rather upvote/share according to their gut feeling. If [this](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/31782580/1) was shared on SO official FB page, you can quit wasting your time on finding reason in SO audits or doing audits altogether.

Comment: When this happens to you and you downvote the question outside of the review queue, it shouldn't be used as an audit case for other users.

Comment: @DavidArenburg that is why we have e.g. [the answer of OpenGL vs DirectX history](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/88055/148803). I bet that if nobody would upvote it *"because it is against the rules"*, the question would become deleted *(now it's just locked)*, and we wouldn't ever knew this epic tale.

Comment: You get this because fixing the review audits is lower priority for SO than lets say designing silly hats or make unicorn mini games.

Comment: You win some, you lose some. I got my first "STOP!" today too for an answer which was marked as spam. Rather than agree it was spam (because it was a serious answer) I decided to edit out the one link to a personal blog that was in there, and got slammed for it :) Do I feel bad? Nope, up yours to the STOP! message, it was wrong and I was right.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Audits are chosen automatically, so you'll get unlucky every now and then.  You're right this question is not on-topic for Stack Overflow.  Unfortunately, this question got a lot of random upvotes, probably from being a Hot Network Question (as [CRABOLO pointed out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303795/i-do-not-understand-why-i-failed-this-audit#comment239842_303795)).  You've done the right thing in bringing attention to this poor audit by posting this question.

Regardless, you should still close/flag the question.  The audit may have been incorrect, but **you still should take actions to fix the situation outside the review queue**.  This could help preventing the audit from being used for other unsuspecting users.  After all, the audit system won't use a closed question as a "good post" audit.

Comment: I also failed in audit of this type of question. If I select "Requires Editing", why the audit is failing me? I did not said that content is "OK".

Comment: @sunrise76 Because "requires editing" means "has formatting/spelling/grammar issues" i.e. something that is fixable by someone else than the author.

Comment: I recently failed an audit by clicking "skip", which I thought was bizarre. The question looked bad, but it was about a subject I knew nothing about, so I thought I'd better let other people judge. Is there a better way to deal with questions that you don't feel qualified to judge?

Comment: @m69 that shouldn't have happened.  Skip never fails audits.  You might want to report that as a new question if you're sure you failed because of a skip.  There's the whole "no shame in skipping" thing.

Comment: @m69''snarkyandunwelcoming'' you probably accidentally pressed on the wrong button (say a co-worker distracts you and you accidentally press Looks Ok or Requires Editing)

Comment: This is exactly why I always open the post in a new tab. So many audits are unfair (especially ones that want you to treat it as a good post).

Answer (score 13):

Of course the question (as stated) is off-topic. But it was upvoted big time, so was one of the answers, no doubt because the user also offered a bounty.

Remember that the process electing posts for review queues can only be a relatively simple algorithm (I mean, relative to the human brain). I don't know how it works, obviously, but no doubt it looks for posts that *look like* candidates for the review queue, but in reality don't qualify for a number of reasons, in which the numbers of upvotes obviously plays a big role. This post slipped through the maze because of the votes.

It happens to all of us once in a while and yes, it's a nuisance, but not one you can't get used to.

---

Seeing the conversations this answer gave rise to, I still wonder what's the big deal? Sometimes we get banned for two days from one of the review queues. [So what](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/157172/168269)? It doesn't take your rep, your badges, your privileges ([well one, temporarily](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158675/168269)). The only bad thing is that benevolent people are not available for a while. It reduces reviewing capacity.

But what's the alternative? It's easy to complain and to stop reviewing altogether, but what do you want, remove the audits? Make them less frequent? People do *anything* to obtain badges. They even [write bots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/298530/861716) to acquire one lousy badge if they can. So I think we all agree we can't do without an effective mechanism to stop these gamers. And as usual, the good also suffer. So either try to live with it or come up with something better.

Comment: however, failed audits impose certain penalties on users, so this has to be **undone** somehow.

Comment: Not if it happens now and then.

Comment: it needs to be undone if it happens *at all.*

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant why? seriously, you have to fail a lot to have any penalties - or even a warning. It's not a black mark against your name. Call it a bad system and be done with it?

Comment: @Tim I pretty much stopped reviewing because of it. I'm sure I'm not the only one. I see the review system as abusive towards the people that are genuinely making the site a better place, and I have low tolerance for such abuse, even if it's coming from a computer rather than a human.

Comment: Really, abusive? That occationally a computer says you are wrong... really? there isn't even a penalty. You're taking it as "A speed camera caught me going at 60 and was wrong and I have to pay" when really there is no fine...

Comment: @Tim Yes, really. And you're wrong that there isn't a penalty. Stay on Meta for a while, you'll see people who ended up with (temporary) system-imposed review bans because of the bad audits.

Comment: @hvd I've never seen one of those posts, and that's pretty unlucky to get 3+ bad audits... So unlikely - i mean there are 10s of 1000s of reviews, and very few of them get this...

Comment: @Tim Sure, it doesn't happen often. If that makes it okay from your point of view, I won't be able to say anything to convince you otherwise. (And I'm not saying you're wrong, just that I don't share your POV.)

Comment: Thought I should let yall know that because of this 'failed' audit I got a two day ban, and this was my first failed audit for a long time @Tim

Comment: @joe_young what's a long time?

Comment: To be honest, longer than I can remember @Tim I would say perhaps a couple of weeks

Comment: I'd be a little concerned about people learning what to expect from the auditing system and just providing what they think the system wants to see rather than a true judgment of the quality of a post.

Comment: @Tim yes, there are consequences. I was once short-term review banned for 2 failed audits in the space of 3 months.  That's extremely harsh when the algorithm choosing audits is that bad.  To be completely fair, one of the failed audits was my fault (too late, too tired) but the other was a bad audit.