# Is this First Posts audit too broad a question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, review-audits, disputed-review-audits, needs-more-focus

I was very close to failing [this audit review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/9714527) in the First Posts queue. I passed by pressing <kbd>No Action Needed</kbd>, but had I not realized it was an audit I would have flagged it as too broad.

[The question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32573540/how-to-allow-for-a-moderator-to-merge-multiple-pending-edits-of-the-same-article) is about how to handle moderation of multiple revisions in a system built using [Ruby on Rails](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_on_Rails). The actual question sentence is:

> How to implement this?

No code. Nothing tested so far. No specific part of the implementation that the OP is stuck on. As I have understood it, questions that are about the best approach to do something quite large and complex is not on-topic. Sure, this one had attracted 15 upvotes and no downvotes, but I suspect that is due to the presence of a bounty. The question is also interesting and well written, which might have helped it gain upvotes, but it doesn't make it any more on-topic.

Am I right in that this question is too broad? Should I flag it? And no matter what the answer to that is, since it is an edge case, could it be removed from the audit list?

**EDIT:** The question is now put on hold as too broad, and I assume that means it is no longer used as an audit.

Comment: *I* would call that too broad.

Comment: And the highest scoring answer is literally "it's possible, parts will be easy, parts will be hard" with *no* insight into an actual programming solution.  I don't know if I can fault the answerer too much given the question, but who actually found that useful?

Comment: If a question draws multiple answers with one that is highly upvoted containing just three paragraphs and was not closed in the past two weeks with over a hundred views then a logical conclusion to draw is that it wasn't too broad.  This is what the audit tests, you were paying attention so you passed.  Whether the Q+A is useful or should have been closed before the OP put a bounty on it, thus preventing SO users from closing it, plays no role in an audit.  That ship has sailed, not that much point in doing it now.

Comment: @HansPassant I strongly disagree. Whether a question "should have been closed before the OP put a bounty on it" should influence how you behave during an audit. The bounty is not even visible from the review page! Are you suggestion that every time I flag a question as "should be closed" in a review, I should first check that there isn't a bounty on it?

Comment: @HansPassant Also, I think I should judge whether a question should be flagged or not based on its actual content, not the number of views, the upvotes on the answers or the time it has been open without getting closed yet. If you came across this question when it was fresh, without any answers, bounty or votes, wouldn't you at least have considered flagging it as too broad?

Comment: Hmya, you voted "no action needed", it is not very obvious why you so strongly disagree with yourself.  A little birdy tells me that you were fully aware that you were being audited and therefore chose another vote than you'd normally pick.  Obviously can do both, you can click Skip if you can't stomach voting intentionally wrong *and* you can revisit the Q+A and vote however you please.

Comment: @HansPassant The little birdy is correct. That is exactly the kind of cognitive dissonance you get when you try to please the magic audit dragons fanciful wishes. Isn't the fact that you have to skip or vote intentionally wrong just to pass an audit a problem? Is it right to punish people who flag a question that should be flagged just because they don't realize that you should not flag questions that should be flagged when it's an audit? Instead you should revisit the question outside of the review system and flag it. How silly of people not to just realize that by themselves.

Comment: No, that's not a problem.  This is a site for programmers.  If being aware of the limitations of a machine causes distress then you picked the wrong job :)

Comment: The review link is to someone else's passed First Posts audit, not your own Triage audit. What's up with that?

Comment: @NathanTuggy No idea why theres a different user. I just copy pasted the URL. Cant find the review in my review history, perhaps audits arent saved? I just realized that it was not triage but first post, though. I mixed them up in my head when I wrote the question - my apologies. I will edit the question.

Comment: @Anders: It's likely that someone else had already finished the audit before you, so it wasn't saved the same way. (Either you took long enough that the 5-minute lock expired, or they did.)

Comment: @NathanTuggy Ah. Yes, I took quite some time. Thanks for fixing the edit, you were quicker than me.

Comment: The fact that the question was successfully answered in two paragraphs suggests to me that it is not too broad.

Comment: @HarryJohnston That's a common fallacy when it comes to Too Broad questions.  People love to answer *extremely* broad questions with woefully incomplete answers.  People will frequently just start to answer the question, provide a bit of information on the topic without actually answering the question as asked.  This is in fact what you see here.  The question is really only "answered" by explaining how to get to the *actual* answer.

Comment: @Servy: looks like a perfectly good answer to me.  Can we get an opinion from a subject-matter expert?  (Are you looking at the last paragraph?  That just outlines an alternative approach, the previous two paragraphs had already answered the question, or so it seems to me.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I do not understand why I failed this audit](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303795/i-do-not-understand-why-i-failed-this-audit)

Comment: @gnat The question is about a specific question, and is now tagged as such. *The only way to keep bad questions out ot the review queues is to start a meta thread about every single bad question in the review queue.* Please do not flag such questions as duplicates.

Comment: @gnat That someone in the past started a discussion about another question does not get the bad question I stumbled upon out of the review queue, which was the purpose of this post.