# Problematic Triage Review Audit: Too Broad

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

I just encountered [this question as an audit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36703477/passing-columns-to-rows-on-python-pandas) on Triage, which obviously was created because the question managed to get six upvotes.

However, there's a massive problem: despite being a Python question, there is **no MCVE**, which is especially inexcusable as the OP mentioned having tried something. The question can easily be interpreted as "giv me da codez!!!" But, obviously, when I went to flag it appropriately (Too Broad, since it asked for new, finished code instead of specific help), I got the notification about the failed audit.

I know this is a somewhat infrequent problem with our review audit system, but I wanted to report this one. If we're going to require [MCVEs](http://www.stackoverflow.com/mcve) in all reasonable scenarios (a-la "what have you tried"), we need to be consistent in our audits as well.

> **NOTE:** I'm disputing this audit for a different reason than the [alleged duplicate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303795/i-do-not-understand-why-i-failed-this-audit). I already know how audits are selected.
>
> **NOTE 2:** From the "duplicate" top answer: "You've done the right thing in bringing attention to this poor audit by posting this question." Based on the negative reception, should I assume this stance has been retracted, and we should no longer report bad audits? (Yes, I already voted to close and DV'd the disputed question.)

Comment: I've been voting to close the question as _too broad_ (and downvoted), the variety of answers already there also tends to indicate this (I'm not a python expert though).

Comment: Why would an MCVE be required here? They're not asking us to debug their code, they're just stating a concrete problem and a rough description of what they had tried. Seems perfectly answerable to me.

Comment: Keep in mind that audits are chosen by an algorithm. It's doubtful that algorithm can tell when an MCVE is posted. So if people upvote the question and _don't_ vote to close it as needing an MCVE (provided it does need one to be answerable, I don't use the tech and can't judge that here) the the algorithm has to assume the question is good and should not be closed.

Comment: @BradLarson, I was under the impression from our help pages that we were in the business of answering questions with specific, verifiable problems, not just "how do I do X?" That's why we have "Unclear What You're Asking" and "Too Broad" as automatic close reasons. Plus, we're not Code Review (which would have been a better fit for this question.)

Comment: For the record, I'm not overly wrankled about the audit. It happens, and it may be one of those disputable things. I clear through almost all the queues every day, and this is the first time I've hit such an audit. (And as @Kendra pointed out, algorithms aren't perfect.) I'm just reporting it, as it appears to be inconsistent with site standards, before it confuses someone else.

Comment: @gnat, nope. Note the `disputed-review-audits` tag - it isn't uncommon for a particular disputed audit to be reported. Furthermore, the reason the audit on the "duplicate" is being disputed is entirely unrelated to this one.

Comment: @JasonMc92 That question would have been close on the spot at Code Review, since we require actual working and valid code in the question. Please before recommending Code Review read this : http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users .

Comment: @Marc-Andre, I know that the code would have been needed in either place. I voted to close as Too Broad IRL, but given an MCVE (my original point here), it would have fit on Code Review, based on your link.

Comment: @JasonMc92 Well it could have fit Code Review but since I believe the OP just want a new solution and not a review of his code, it may not have been a well receive questions. That's probably why the OP did not include the code and just explain his problem.

Comment: @Marc-Andre, *exactly*, thank you. That's my original point. The mention of Code Review was in response to Brad. "giv me da codez!!!" is not in site scope *anywhere* on the Stack Exchange network, and that's exactly how this comes across. Thus why the audit is disputed.

Comment: Since the distinction is unclear, I edited the question to clarify: the lack of an MCVE pointed to a request for new, finished code, which by site precedence and every official document I've seen, makes it "too broad".

Answer (score 4):

> The question can easily be interpreted as "giv me da codez!!!" But, obviously, when I went to flag it appropriately, I got the notification about the failed audit.... we need to be consistent in our audits as well.

We are being consisten in the audits because this question does not deserve to be closed.  [You should not close a "give me teh codez" question for laziness](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253096/4320665).  Other close reasons like "duplicate", "too broad", or "unclear" are possibly applicable, and some deserve a downvote for "lack of research". But most of them are answerable and should not be closed. In this regard, it's good thing you failed an audit for closing a question that doesn't deserve to be closed.  I'm not an expert in python, but the question seems to be narrow enough to not be too broad.  And it is completely understandable and answerable.

As for the downvotes on this meta post, please don't take them personally.  I think they represent the community disagreeing with the premise of your question (that the question is in fact a bad audit).  If you want to start new discussions about future audits, meta is the place to ask.

Comment: If what you say is true, why do we have [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)? Can we *please* have a consistent set of community standards *somewhere*? Yes, I'm irritated, because the "official" definition of what is in-topic and out-of-topic is hit-and-miss at best.

Comment: What's inconsistent within that page to what I've posted?  __Not all questions benefit from including code__

Comment: We also have "Too Broad" and "Off Topic" (lacking clear question, MCVE, and/or error) flags. All I'm asking is, if that's not required, *why are those there*? That page is inconsistent with other official help documents, which is what's driving me nuts.

Comment: And none of those flags are applicable.  The question isn't too broad, and it's not lacking an MCVE because the question doesn't need an MCVE. It isn't a debugging question dealing with fixing code.

Comment: Okay, so in short, if they ask for us to give them the code, although that is frequently stated as being "too broad" for our site, we leave it alone? If that's the case, that needs to actually go in the help documents *somewhere*, instead of just on a random meta question.

Comment: @JasonMc92 yes that's correct.  Of course, if you think that this problem actually is too broad feel free to downvote or close vote that way.  You'd still fail this audit, but it would have been a much more justifiable position (because broadness is subjective).  The main thing to remember is that downvotes and close votes are different things and have different uses.