# Why is this considered a good question?

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I just came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46980225/how-long-does-stack-keep-the-packages-in-its-cache) in a review queue. What first tipped me off was that the question in the title "*How long does stack keep the packages in its cache?*" has nothing to do with the question in the body, where the user said they wanted to build their own cache and asked about "ideas considered when building `stack`".

All of this has lead me to believe that this question is primarily opinion-based and thus I flagged it as such. The system however considers it to be a "clear and answerable question", which took me by surprize.

As such, I would like to know if this is a good question, and if so, why is it not considered opinion-based?

Comment: Ugh. The way it's written I want to at least downvote it, but I'm also eying that "primarily opinion based" close option. However, it received a very nice answer which makes me suspect I'm not seeing the actual meat of the question due to a lack of domain knowledge. It may just need a little editing to make it a better question.

Comment: @Gimby There is this weird schism between asking how a certain piece of software is used/implemented and how caching can be implemented in general, which causes this to be a very difficult-to-read question; at least for me.

Comment: see also: [I do not understand why I failed this audit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/303802/839601)