# Review Queue audit may no longer be relevant

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

I just got caught in the following close review queue audit:

[Sign in with google prevents the user to sign in again with different account - iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49256119/3077495)

I don't know when this became an audit, but apparently the problem was caused by a bug that has since been fixed (see the comments), the most recent comment having been posted yesterday - that the problem no longer occurs.

Given that information, I proposed to close the Question as off-topic, no longer reproducible. And was told that this is an audit and I failed, my answer was incorrect.

I think the audit needs to be reviewed, given the most recent information...

Comment: If you think that the question merits closure then vote to close it, and it will no longer qualify as a possible audit.

Comment: Hah! Always learning... Done. Didn't realize that was possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I do not understand why I failed this audit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303795/i-do-not-understand-why-i-failed-this-audit)

Comment: @gnat No, I'm not asking that. If the comments about it being a bug, that has since been fixed, hadn't been there I would have voted differently and not failed. My concern was completely about getting this out of the review queue since the situation had obviously changed.

Comment: A single comment stating _"Working fine now"_ isn't a good reason to close the question in my eyes. Also i just checked the github issue and that is still open with the last comment 10 hours ago stating it isn't fixed yet.

Comment: To add to my previous comment. If it was the person who asked the question that commented it was working I agree it should be closed as off-topic.

Comment: @AndréKool And given that it's a software bug, whether fixed or not, I question that it's on-topic at all. It's not something anyone can answer - it's not a programming question in that sense. It's a problem, but not a question that needs to stay on the site.