# Possible bad audit - First Posts: "Xcode 10b5 - [...]"

Tags: support, disputed-review-audits, first-post-review

I just went to fail with the following audit in **First Posts** (on the answer):

> [Xcode 10b5 - duplicate symbol linker error, can't compile with Crashlytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51602785/xcode-10b5-duplicate-symbol-linker-error-cant-compile-with-crashlytics#answer-51828194)
>   [First Posts Review link](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/20779319)

I should have review it positively but I did not (I flagged it as *"Not an answer"*).

**I understand that the system chose this question** because it has many upvotes and is an accepted answer. The issue was probably caused by a bug that have been fixed in the next version, therefore the answer is not really wrong.

But looking from here it looks like a *"comment-answer"* with *low-quality content*. I think this is a bad audit because we can review it negatively even while paying attention.

Comment: I just think this shouldn't be an audit as it is really confusing

Comment: Reading the comments and seeing the upvotes (after failing) I understood it was the solution, but while reviewing, it looks like a really bad answer.

Comment: Short answers are answers. However, NAA is notorious for catching people out. NAA means that it isn't an answer in the terms that it is a comment or an answer asking for clarification.

Comment: It looks like a really bad answer, or it looks like _it's not an answer?_ That's an important difference. If it just looks like a _bad_ answer, then it is still an answer. If it looks like it's _not an answer_ then flagging it make sense.

Comment: I flagged it because it looked like a comment like *"it works for me !"*

Comment: _"It works for me"_ is indeed a _bad_ answer, but with some more follow-up, could be _the_ answer: _"It works for me, so check x setting in y menu to make sure it's configured properly!"_ for example. That it's short does not make it not an answer- It just means it's short, _possibly_ low quality. But they said _exactly_ what they did that worked for them, that fixed the issue. That's the most important part of an answer.

Comment: @AymDev but you are missing out an important part, they specified what they did to fix. No matter how insignificant that might be but that solved it therefore it is an answer. Like I said NAA catches out a lot of people (just check out how many times I've brought up NAA disputes myself).

Comment: Okay, I'll keep your comments in mind, then.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I do not understand why I failed this audit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303795/i-do-not-understand-why-i-failed-this-audit)

Comment: I do understand why I failed. But I thought this was anyway a bad audit (at least for paying attention).

Comment: I'm pretty sure audits are automated. They could even just be incorrect. Don't sweat it if you miss one.

Comment: @TheWanderer yes they are automated and a question (don't have the link rn) tells to ask on meta sites as I did if we think we encountered a bad audit.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The audit was correct, actually: That post is an answer.

Super-amazing-ultra-high-quality answer? Not really. Clear, and clearly useful, answer? Yeah, pretty much.

That answer says to update to the newest version. That's an answer. That's not a comment.

This is actually a good audit, in terms of teaching users what is and isn't an answer, though I doubt it's that good in making sure someone's paying attention.

For the future, remember: If it looks like an answer, even a *poor* or *wrong* answer, then NAA is the *wrong* flag. That is for posts that are 100% categorically not in the realm of being an answer, such as follow-up questions, *"I like pie"* and any nonsense that you can tell is not an answer without having to look into it at all.

Comment: I will remember that for my future reviews. Thanks (I'll accept as soon as I can).

Comment: If the VLQ flag is brought back, we'd have a lot less NAA flag mistakes.

Comment: @Script47 What's the VLQ flag ? Very Low Quality ? Oh and I browsed your question history, I understand what you meant :)

Comment: @AymDev yes, that is exactly what VLQ means.

Comment: @Script47 The VLQ flag still exists.  That said, it's not for answers that you think are bad.  It's for answers that are both completely garbage and also unsalvageable (meaning it has basically 100% overlap with NAA).  This answer is neither of those things.  If you think an answer isn't useful, downvote it.  That's the mechanism to provide your feedback on a post's quality.

Comment: @Servy I wasn't aware the the VLQ flag is still around (thanks) and neither do I think this answer is VLQ or NAA (check my comment in the OP chain). I was just commenting in general.