# Why was my review inappropriate for this particular audit?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, questions, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I was reviewing (first posts) and came across the following question:

> Below error while gradle sync Failed in Mac.
>
> CONFIGURE FAILED in 3s
>   `ERROR: No signature of method: com.crashlytics.tools.gradle.CrashlyticsPlugin.findObfuscationTransformTask() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [Debug]`
>
> Project works fine in Windows

I thought *okay, this person is new here and doesn't know that you need to put more details as to why this is a problem and improve the quality of the question*, so I downvoted it.  The issue is legitimate and I figured that if others had the same problem, they could refer back to this.  It turned out this was an audit and I failed.  Was this question unsalvageable? 
 Was it OK?  The audit said `This question has been taken care of`, and yet when I do a simple search on SO for the question, it is *still there* and has 16 upvotes.  How was this taken care of?

EDIT: review link: https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/22600828

EDIT for Pikachu: [image]

EDIT:  This question is not a duplicate of [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303795/i-do-not-understand-why-i-failed-this-audit) because it is a different question and a different audit, and I more than likely have a different history than the other poster.

Comment: @PikachuthePurpleWizard I *think* I downvoted it then

Comment: Ban should be the result of multiple review failed. Btw require edit is when the post just require edit. If the question is 5 line mono block debuging question with no mcve, it's not a require edit.

Comment: @gnat No, it is not because the possible one discusses another review audit.

Comment: @smileycreations15 see [answer over there](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/303802/839601), it totally applies, "You've done the right thing in bringing attention to this poor audit by posting this question. Regardless, you should still close/flag the question..." (note how accepted answer here says essentially the same)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The review you mentioned was a known-good review audit. This means that, to pass it, you had to perform an upvote, edit, comment, or review as No Action Needed (at least I think those are the actions). You said you downvoted, which is what made you fail the audit.

Now, whether or not it's a *valid* audit is a different story. The question contains very little detail and shows no effort from the OP. It should be closed as "questions seeking debugging help must include a minimal, complete, and verifiable example". The reason for the upvotes is probably because it's a common problem and users who came across it upvoted it because it was useful to them, even though it's a bad question.

Downvoting and flagging for closure are two good options here. You made the right decision by downvoting, and should continue to do so in the future. I have flagged the question for closure, so hopefully it won't be used as an audit in the future ([no, this was not the first case](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55194687/timeline)).

Comment: Thanks, do you know if there is a way to appeal the suspension?

Comment: @Jodast this post on meta is fine. A moderator'll find it and unban you from review.

Comment: One is never banned for failing just one audit. There must be several other incorrect decisions in your recent history, @Jodast. Unless you can provide evidence that *all* of those are wrong (or at least more than one), I don't have a compelling reason to lift the review suspension, even though I agree that this particular audit was a bad one. In fact, this is your second automated review suspension this month.

Comment: @CodyGray okay, although I haven't failed an audit in a while (relatively speaking, in relation to how long I've been reviewing for)

Comment: @Jodast if you can find other audits that you disagree with, you can post about them on meta as well. If there were other legitimate audits you failed, then learn from your mistakes and come back when your review ban's timed out. Don't worry, I've been banned from review *countless* times, but I've learned from my mistakes and become a fairly good reviewer.

Comment: Not countless. I can count it. :-p

Comment: @CodyGray I'm actually curious now... how many review bans have I had? (you can write a comment; I don't care if other people know)

Comment: Okay. I was going to say it the first time, but I was afraid of divulging private seekrits. It's only been 5 times. Three were automatic (based on failed audits); two were manually imposed by a moderator (not me this time, oddly). Most everyone's been suspended at least once or twice. Audits are...not always good.

Comment: Wow... that's actually a lot less than I thought. I thought it was more around 8 or 9. Hopefully it'll stay at 5 though...

Comment: The durations of suspensions increase linearly when the suspensions are imposed within a relatively short period of time, and that did happen to you, so it might have felt like you were suspended from reviewing for eternity, even though there weren't that many total suspensions. The exact rules for how this works are complicated, and I've never bothered to memorize them. I'm sure you can find them either here or on [Meta.SE]. Basic pattern is something like 2 days, 4 days, 8 days, 16 days, 32 days. No suspensions are ever permanent, even manually-imposed.

Comment: I think I saw somewhere on MSE that it starts with 2, then 4, then 8, then 16... I must admit, though, my last(?) review ban really did feel like an eternity. I think it was either 32 or 64 days. But considering how obsessed I was with reviewing at the time...

Comment: so then yeah it's exponential not linear.  I can say that PtPW's most recent suspension was 32 days.  I think that the suspension time should be based on a logistic function, not exponential (but I can't say for sure if there is a cap on days one can be suspended for).

Comment: @CodyGray I'm not sure I agree with your reasoning for not lifting the suspension. That's like saying that someone who is accused of a crime but proven innocent should go to jail anyway if they have a criminal record. It's conflating punishments.

Comment: No, @Robert, it's like someone who has already gotten three DUIs proving that they were under the legal limit this time. Like I said, you don't get automatically banned from failing one audit, so there's a *pattern* here. More than one audit has been failed, and without evidence that those audits were *also* wrong (which would be pretty exceptional), I don't see any justification for taking action. It's not like this is a 30-day suspension or something silly. It lifts in 4 days. I don't really want to take the time to dig through their history and see if lifting the suspension is warranted.

Comment: @CodyGray the way I see it is, Jodast would not currently suspended if it weren't for this invalid audit. While there were some possibly bad reviews in the past, the system doesn't determine them to have been enough, because, as I said before, Jodast wouldn't have ever been banned if it weren't for an invalid review audit.

Comment: I'm afraid that two different things are being conflated here. There is a reviewer's *recent history*, which is used for escalating the time period of a suspension. That comes from suspensions that have *already been handed out*. Then, separate from that, there is the fact that it requires failing *multiple audits* to be subject to a suspension. This latter case is the applicable one here. Even if one audit is proven to be a dud, it doesn't invalidate the *other* audits that had to be failed to earn that suspension. Yes, I guess it's a "straw that broke the camel's back" thing, such that...

Comment: ...it is trivially true that if they hadn't failed this audit, they *might* not have passed the threshold yet to earn a suspension, but you don't actually know that, because they might have failed a valid audit immediately after this one (we just don't know because they were suspended first). Furthermore, if I unban, it resets the counter of failed audits, so that would effectively be giving someone a "get out of jail free" card (to use Robert's analogy) just because they proved that *one  fact* in the case against them was wrong.

Comment: @Pikachu exactly. With the DUI example, the argument becomes, "Well, two DUIs isn't enough to send you to jail. Even though you were acquitted this third time, you are 'obviously' a drunk and belong in jail, so we will put you there anyway."

Comment: I can see the reasoning behind both sides of the argument... @Jodast if you're okay with it, would you mind posting a screenshot of what you see at stackoverflow.com/review? It should show what other audits you've failed, and from there we can more accurately decide if your review suspension was really necessary.

Comment: @CodyGray the way I see it, *one* DUI is enough for a punishment.  let's say that, hypothetically, three failed audits in recent history is enough for a punishment.  The two previous failed audits are within the legal limit, but the most recent illegitimate failed audit is not (even though I didn't deserve it).  I *should* still be within the legal limit for audits.  With the law, the rules were set that one DUI is enough for punishment.  with SO, the rules were set that three audits failed is enough for punishment, so I am technically withint the defined rules as being law-abiding.

Comment: @PikachuthePurpleWizard Posted it, I can't see anything besides the one link

Comment: @Jodast it seems that, in this case, you were banned because you failed one audit but also had a recent review ban. It is still from failing multiple audits, but some went into your previous review ban. The only way to find them is to go digging through your whole [review history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9808974/jodast?tab=activity), which takes a *long* time. Feel free to do so if you wish, though, and post a link to the audits you failed in the question or a comment.

Answer (score 6):

Update: It's already closed.

---

I'm voting to close that question.
I met similar situation before, double checked the question/review task I failed, and *learned* to be careful.
I think the system is using many wrong examples to audit users, this needs to be improved.

However, to be prudent, it's better to open the question you're reviewing, to see if it's  well-received.
A well-received question, in SO's eyes, though lack of other good points, is still a *good* question.

Comment: I agree, the system does have some flaws.  I usually try to open a question before I review, and I did for this question. It looked well recieved.  I honestly think that the audit system is broken and a bit too harsh.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am using the **skip** button a lot more and more.

Comment: @SecretAgentMan using skip is not a bad thing. Furthermore if you _are_ sure of your decision _and_ you're paying attention, and you still fail the audit, then make a case on meta. Either you are proven right and the audit gets expelled from the pool, or you learn something new. Skipping reviews where you are not sure of the correct action is good.