# Why was a question that didn't ask a question a review audit?

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits, triage

I was reviewing Triage when I came across this review:

[image: Failed review]

This question didn't ask a question or show research, so I marked it Unsalvageable. After all, the [Help Center > Asking > How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) says, in large print,

> Search, and research

and I sure hate to assume a question someone hasn't asked when the title of the question implies a discussion rather than an answer. From the [Help Center > Asking > What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

> Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.

**Should this question be an audit?**

Note: This question is not the same as the [potential duplicate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303795/i-do-not-understand-why-i-failed-this-audit), because that question actually asks a question.

Comment: Because (A) people will upvote any darn thing, and (B) people don't vote to close enough things, and (C) people don't make enough edits.

Comment: I would have marked the first and third comments as "No longer needed"... The second comment answers the problem, although indirectly. And since it's obvious from the information in the question what is being asked, the question could have been edited to include a question, if one were so inclined.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I do not understand why I failed this audit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303795/i-do-not-understand-why-i-failed-this-audit)

Comment: @CodyGray (A) This is an indicator that a lot of people are running into the same problem. Referring to recent conversations about the site: If you come down on the side of "welcoming all coders" then this is the kind of content that will be asked and become acceptable. It's a lot better than some of the things I've been seeing, increasingly...

Comment: @CindyMeCindy Although i understand your point, I sure hate to put words into people's mouths by formulating my own question.

Comment: I agree, which is why I phrased it as I did :-) I have done so, on occasion, when other edits were necessary - especially grammar and when the user is new to the site and may not realize the requirements... and when I felt the question otherwise "legitimate"... and when comments indicate some people in review weren't recognizing what was being asked. But it happens rarely.

Comment: @CindyMeister What I meant was that I if were to ask a question for someone, I could be wrong about the question the OP meant to ask. Most of my edits are adding image descriptions for accessibility or grammar fixes, not anything that would change the meaning of the question.

Comment: @CindyMeister and Cody Gray, (A) could also be people reacting to the tone of the title and the 3rd comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The question has been improved, so it seems at least this one won't misleading anyone else now.

---

I think the system should try to improve the audit-choosing algorithm, at least try to avoid using those short posts as audit ones cause there's big chance of those being edge cases.

**Be careful** when you are reviewing, *before the system updated*, open the question to check if the post is well-received, if it's already well-received then skip it or choose *OK* even though it's a bad one.

Comment: I'll heed your warning, but it was my third review audit this evening.

Answer (score 9):

It is easy to see which question is asked.

There are three examples of a line of code, two works one not. The code is annotated to indicate which line errors. The exact error message is present.

The title said:

> Weird behavior of anonymous function with placeholder

As it isn't strictly needed to repeat the title in the question (like What causes this weird behavior of anonymous function with placeholder) I honestly can't understand why you claim there is no question asked.

To prevent anymore close and down voters to cause havoc on that question (and its answer)  I gave it an edit that addresses most of your concerns and I propose you do the same for the next audit you fail instead of bringing it to Meta.

I've seen the argument being used that more reviewers have failed that audit. That is a problem with the reviewers not with the question under scrutiny. Skip is an under used option, nobody have to judge posts you know nothing about.

If that question gets closed, I'll vote to reopen it. It already has my up vote.

Comment: Just retracted my close vote. Anyway I don't see any havoc happening, imho the question itself does not deserve many upvotes so a couple of downvotes to neutralize it seems reasonable. As an edge case it shouldn't be used as audit question in the first place.

Comment: @Tiw you can use your votes (close, up, down, delete) however you want. I personally never use votes to for the purpose to neutralize things. I accept we differ on opinion whether this is an edge case or not. If you think it is, vote accordingly. This is fine.

Comment: *I honestly can't understand why you claim there is no question asked.* We'll have to agree to disagree on this point.