# Why did I fail an audit once again?

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits, review-suspension

I came across this question ([How to fix this app:transform Dex With Instant Run Slices Apk For Debug?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55848601)) in the [first post review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/22978181) which was used to test me.

It contains the question once in the title and twice in the same words in the body, and a very huge stacktrace. That's why I've voted to close the question as "Too broad", and I failed the audit.

Even if my Java knowledge is a bit outdated, this looks pretty broad to me: the problem statement looks pretty broad to me, contains only very little information about the setup, no code. After all, even if it has attracted 13 upvotes, it should have been closed earlier, or not used for audits after all.

Having failed some other (IMHO disputable) audits in between, the current ban is eight days. I start to question that process more and more. Yes, that might be a legit process to stop people that "abuse" the system, but it also offends the ones that want to contribute to Stack Overflow in this way.

As I've asked some times already: is there a way to inspect the list of failed audit questions (not just the most recent one)? I'd like to see if there is anything I could learn from this, or whether this is only pure annoyance.

Comment: [The audit in question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/22978181)

Comment: Can you please narrow down the question, please? Are you asking for this audit to be removed from the audit pool? To lift the audit ban? To see if there is a way to see failied review audits?

Comment: What action did you take that caused you to fail this audit?

Comment: I would advise to **filter** the review queues to tags you are very famiilar with. It makes this kind of thing much less likely.

Comment: @yivi thanks for additional questions. I'd love to get the opinion of others about that special question (is it wrong that I voted to close it?), and about it being a legit audit question

Comment: @yivi additionally, lifting the ban does help for the short-time until the next "illegit" audit catches me, and filtering the queue (which sounds really good) does not help either. What if I were an expert on such questions and vote to close it anyways?

Comment: In my experience, it's very, very easy to sniff out audits in tags if you are filtering by tags you are very familiar with.

Comment: Typical audit case, the machine picks a very popular Q+A (50 helpful votes for this one) and when you want to kill it then it assumes you didn't look.  You have to stop and look, like the audit says, or you'll just keep failing them over and over again.

Comment: But then: what's the thing behind audits if I have to trick them? Do you think this is a question that should stay open? Besides helping someone with that exact error question and the lucky guy who understood and solved it, is this the kind of question that should occur on SO?

Comment: It's not to "trick" them. It's to help you out. In the end it's the same thing: you need to pay attention. But you'll be less likely to be caught by bad apples. It's just a piece of advise. You'll be able to continue reviewing with less annoyances. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: @HansPassant as far as I see, that question got 14 votes and not 50. So the bar must be lower - and no, even by "stop and look", I would have voted to close this question

Comment: @yivi so what do you mean by "pay attention"? Open each question in a new tab to check for votes? Not choosing the **proper** action when I've identified that I'm put under test, but to choose the action that allows me to review further even if that is not the proper action? That's what I mean by "trick the system"

Comment: "Identifying audits" is part of the proof you are paying enough attention, generally speaking. Audits are maybe more an attention test than a "choose wisely" test. If you filter by tags, you'll have an easier way. Or don't, and continue tripping with these cases.

Comment: There isn't anything wrong with the question.  Build tools failing for inscrutable reasons is a too common mishap, it gets popular when it happens to a lot of other programmers and they can easily google the stack trace content.  Meat and potatoes of Q+A and a gold mine to anybody that suffered the same fate.

Comment: The question received several downvotes and close votes since you brought it up. Whatever happens with the question later on, it's not likely to appear in the audit pool again.

Comment: Also useful for spotting audits is following the [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rHX8.png) - often the vote count is different in the real post.

Comment: I know that I can follow the link, but still it looks like tricking for me that I should perform one action to succeed the audit (even if that action looks wrong to me) and another action in another tab to perform what I think I should do (vote to close the question), but are not able to do during the audit

Comment: I didn't mean that you should follow the link to figure out how to pass the audit. I meant that you can follow the link to know you are in an audit. You can then skip it, or ask about it on meta.

Comment: @NicoHaase if you're being audited, usually what you believe should happen no longer needs to be done; the content has already been dealt with. The audit is simply showing you fake news.

Comment: I failed my [3rd audit of the day](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/382007/why-was-a-question-that-didnt-ask-a-question-a-review-audit) once. I failed only once because I haven't done any reviews since. Some audits just aren't that good.

Comment: @yivi: Are you sure you want me to start advocating detecting and skipping all audits, because that's the logical end-result of your proposal. Nothing good can come of taking any action on an audit once you've identified it as one.

Comment: @NicoHaase I usually do what you say: check for audit, do "right" action in review and do really what I want in another tab. This is how the system works...

Comment: The worst part of this really bad audit question is that the answer is a direct cut and paste from the answer to another question. I've flagged it for moderator attention. I must say I'm at a loss as to how either the question or answer got so many upvotes...

Comment: @Nick as an Android app developer who uses Android Studio, Gradle, its build tool and how it easily breaks with every major update, I wasn't surprised it received many upvotes...

Comment: @AndrewT. obviously I need to learn about Gradle and answer questions. I *dream* of getting 38 upvotes on an answer! :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I do not understand why I failed this audit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303795/i-do-not-understand-why-i-failed-this-audit)

Comment: @gnat: Not a dupe. Moderator intervention was called for. See Yvette Columb's answer.

Comment: Even is that question isn't that good, why do people still vote for it after following the link from the question, image you are the OP of that question, and you suddenly receive a lot of  downvotes, without knowing whats going it, how would you feel, all those drive by downvotes are really unfriendly

Answer (score 32):

That's a trash question that contains pretty much nothing but a backtrace and most of the exception text. Unfortunately the text near the end that could conceivably uniquely identify the problem has cut off.

You are right and the audit mechanism is wrong. That question is now being blasted from meta effect.

A month since this posting, a serious attempt has been made at fixing this question. To fully understand how bad the audit was, see [this revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/55848601/3). I will not be able to make a serious attempt at assessing the question after its modifications.

Comment: I've got to echo Hans's comment questioning whether this is really a "trash question". It's certainly poorly asked and could be improved by editing, but judging by the votes, lots of people with exactly the same build tool failure were able to find and understand it despite its sloppiness and were helped by its answer. I'm not going to touch it since I'm not an Android guy, but it looks to me like what it really needs is not closure but rather an edit by someone familiar with Android to add in some actual sentences coherently explaining what triggers this error and in what circumstances.

Comment: @MarkAmery: I wouldn't have voted to close if so much as the exception text wasn't cut off. If the problem's that easily found the question is easy to fix but noone does so.

Comment: Again, I'm not an Android guy and I may be wildly wrong, but I *guess* that the exception text is cut off because that's exactly how the build tools output it. Even if it's theoretically possible to use a forked version of the tools to get a less crappy traceback out when they crash, that would be entirely the wrong thing to do if it's not representative of the error that actual users of the tools will see. If the real-world build-time crash that people see emits only a crappy truncated traceback, then that crappy truncated traceback is what belongs in the Stack Overflow question about it.

Comment: @MarkAmery Confirmed. The OP hasn't cut it off, that's just a normal JVM stacktrace cutoff. The most important bit of the trace is the first few lines anyway.

Comment: I've tried to edit it a bit to make it a little more readable, but so far have struggled to make it make a lot of sense.

Comment: @JamesRiordan I think one particularly valuable thing to add that's currently missing is when and where the error appears. I'm not even sure, reading without context, whether it's a run-time error (i.e. the app launches, then crashes when you try to use some particular feature in it, and spits out the error shown) or a compile-time error (i.e. you hit the "run" button in Android Studio, it starts trying to compile the app, but the compilation fails and spits out the error shown in some pane in Android Studio somewhere). Just clarifying that, while not all there is to do, would be a good start.

Comment: @JamesRiordan I can easily imagine a version of the question that reads "I have an Android app I am writing using version X of Android Studio, version Y of Gradle, and version Z of [whatever other relevant tools]. When I do [something], the app [does/does not] launch and then I see this error [somewhere]:" followed by the traceback. That version of the question, I think, would not have been a magnet for close votes. But I can't transform the question into that state myself, because I don't have the Android knowledge needed to populate any of the placeholders in the template I just wrote.

Comment: @JamesRiordan (Even better would be a version that also has short step-by-step instructions to create a minimal app that reproduces this error - but I'm not sure whether that's something you'd be able to provide.)

Comment: @MarkAmery I can't edit this because I can't get rid of the error reading: 'It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.' I've tried adding lots more detail, but I ultimately can't save my edits. Can I have moderator intervention to be able to edit this?

Comment: @JamesRiordan Oh, boy. Those post quality filters have a history of occasionally being, uh, a tad problematic. I don't think they're any more forgiving for some users than others, unfortunately. Reckon you could quote what you want to edit the question to in an answer here (or, uh, on pastebin or something if the system won't even let you do that) and I'll see if I can find a way to tweak it so it gets past the quality filter?

Comment: So this is a good deal better: https://pastebin.com/i4Jq5613, but I can't do much more without more info of what the OP was doing. I'm struggling for a minimal example because, to be honest, I've no idea exactly why this happens. I just spent ages trying to fix it and left the answer here.

Comment: @JamesRiordan: If you're seeing it maybe you can correct or explain the cut-off path in the exception text.

Comment: It's a standard JVM printout. The JVM cuts off long exception messages.

Comment: @JamesRiordan Apparently the quality filter discriminates based on the user's rep; *you* might not be able to make the edit you wanted to, but *I* can. I have implemented your changes.

Comment: @JamesRiordan ... although it looks to me like you messed up some of the formatting of the traceback in the course of editing? I'll fix that.

Comment: @JamesRiordan I've also attempted to fix the incoherent nonsense in the title. Does my new title look sensible to you?

Comment: @MarkAmery Yeah that new title is much better Cheers.

Comment: @JamesRiordan You're welcome - and thanks for putting in the work on your end. I've chucked a reopen vote at the question, for whatever it's worth, but a check in SEDE suggests that that has not pushed it into the Reopen queue. I'll leave it up to you to decide if you're invested enough in the question want to do anything further (like raise a mod flag or make a Meta post arguing for reopening).

Answer (score 21):

You've been unbanned from reviewing.

A question like that, with a stack trace dump and nothing else is usually failing to provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It's not a good audit candidate.

Audit candidates are selected automatically. There's been tweaks to improve the audit selection. The best thing to do is either raise a mod flag or write a question here.

Comment: It would be good to have a manual way to prevent posts being used as audits.

Comment: There is: edit them. Or, you know, close and downvote them.

Comment: @CodyGray editing them doesn't remove them from the audit pool.

Comment: @YvetteColomb It prevents them from being shouldn't be in an audit.