# Banned from reviewing once more

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits, review-suspension

A review ban has struck me once more on a question that got upvoted mysteriously from my POV: https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/25301297 - as using testing on a day-by-day basis and having implemented tons of CI pipelines, this looks way to vague for me and that's why I've flagged this question - and got banned.

When I got banned the last time in May 2019, some "improvements" should have been implemented in the system. How's the current state of that if a ban can still happen on such a question?

Comment: If you strongly feel this audit is inappropriate, simply vote to close and it will no longer be used as an audit. *[hint to never fail an audit again](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/ReviewQueueHelper.user.js)*

Comment: What "improvements" do you refer to? What were you hoping to see? Had you clicked through the audit, it would have been obvious that this was a self-answered question.

Comment: @CodyGray accoridng to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/384879/1116230, something has been improved in the process

Comment: @SamuelLiew yeah, that's what I did: voting to close it, got banned as this was an audit question, then voted to close it again. But my question remains: should this be a question to trigger an audit which might trigger a ban? If not, could anybody lift that ban?

Comment: The audit process is deeply flawed, and has been since it was introduced. There does not appear to be much desire on the part of the company to address it. Hence, I stay away from the review queues.

Answer (score 6):

The only recent changes I am aware of are about things like *close* messages and such. And for example the reduction of votes required for closing questions.

Thing is: the review system is partially broken.

The two major things to know when using it:

- *skip* is your best friend. Only vote when you are really sure.
- Every time you think you were wrongly caught by the auto-system: take a note. Write down the URL of the dubious content, and maybe even write down why you voted against the system. And then: in case you get banned from reviewing, raise a flag to moderation, and provide that history of wrong "audit results". Then the moderators can chime in and lessen or drop the review penalty.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. One thing I've definitely learned from the last bans is that skipping is really important, and I'm skipping way more than months ago. But it looks a bit strange to me that I should come to meta and complain about IMHO wrong audits....

Comment: @NicoHaase Sorry for not being precise enough. You dont turn to meta. You turn to the moderators. See my reworked second bullet point.

Comment: "*skip is your best friend*"  (+1)

Comment: Meta is a good place to find moderators, so I'm not sure why you are drawing this distinction. A Meta question is a good place to lay out that evidence you mention.

Comment: @CodyGray Because a META post goes out to possibly hundreds of users. Which might then go and scan your profile for whatever. I have seen more than once that I asked a question here and a few minutes later, I had multiple downvotes on different posts on the main site. That kills motivation to ask, and worse: trust into th community. That is the difference between putting up a request to a limited number of moderators, and the community as a whole.

Comment: Well, you're not going to have much luck using moderator flags to ask for a re-evaluation of your review ban, so Meta is really your best bet. Not only do you not have enough room in the flag message to cite all of the evidence you've collected, but that simply isn't the right forum to open up a discussion with moderators. Any such flags are likely to be declined. Maybe the reason you've had downvotes on your posts if that users thought they were "unclear or not useful"?

Comment: @CodyGray If so, that is a change in policy. Because that is exactly what I did in the past, and it worked. No declined flags, but a reduced review ban. Besides, since when do have meta users the ability to influence the review ban of another user? In the end it is still a moderator making the decision, and hitting some button?! Finally: I really don't get why you blame targeted voting on me now. When I post a question **here**, and then suddenly I saw multiple downvotes on **main** ... how could that be about "unclear and not useful"?

Comment: It's not a change in policy, you just happened to have your flag reviewed by a moderator who was nice enough to reduce the ban. We are pretty nice people, and we generally will do nice things, but that doesn't mean that flags are a good place to ask for this sort of thing. If you want to appeal a ban or any other moderator decision, Meta is the appropriate place to do that. The fact that other community members can't reverse it doesn't matter. Mods read the posts on Meta, and Meta is the only place we can have a discussion about it. Flags are merely to alert us to problematic content.

Comment: I'm not *blaming* you for anything regarding voting. I'm simply pointing out that you have no idea whether there is a connection between your posting on Meta and your receiving votes on main. Stack Overflow has a *lot* of users with voting privileges, any of which  could be reading your posts at any given time and voting as they see fit. Even *if* people came across your posts via Meta, I still don't see what's wrong with them voting as they see fit on the content of those posts.