# The answer was not that bad (as compared to the others) to be present in the audit

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

Here is [my failed review-audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/23343364).

The (now deleted) answer is certainly not of the best quality; however, I would not categorize it as "link-only". Moreover, the two existing answers for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4565002/2452869) do not provide much more information, as compared to the "failed review audit answer".

Again, the deleted answer from the review is not the best; however, it is not worse than the answers in the question, still provides valuable information "in-text" and not via link, and certainly should not be used for the audit purpose, in my opinion.

Comment: I stopped reviewing after failing [this audit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/382007/why-was-a-question-that-didnt-ask-a-question-a-review-audit), my 3rd audit of the evening. I decided that I had better things to do.

Comment: Whether other answers on that question are good or not have no bearing on whether the answer you're *reviewing* needs no action (except in the case of plagarism / identical code / identical explanation given by an earlier answer). Sure, other answers are poor too, but this one deserves improvement as well.

Comment: @yivi that's not a duplicate. This is an initiative to exclude a particular question from the "audit" line.

Comment: The duplicate would show you how you should have acted with reviews like this one; making any other action unnecessary. The audit does not need to be removed; you need to change your reviewing strategy.

Comment: @yivi I am arguing that my reviewing strategy is ok.

Comment: If you check it against the linked guide, you’ll see that choosing “no action needed” here wasn’t “ok”. Good luck!

Comment: @CertainPerformance To determine if something is good, both relative and absolute scales have to be used (of course, IMHO). **Absolute**: to perform cut-offs for certainly terrible and certainly good answers. **Relative**: to judge whether for this question and given family of answers the answer deserves to survive.

Comment: That's not how things work here. Just for example, a link-only answer on a question which happens to contain a couple spam answers too is still a link-only answer and worthy of deletion. When looking at Late Answers, if an answer looks lacking, you should prompt the poster to fix it. Maybe the answer shouldn't have been deleted, but "No action needed" *definitely* isn't the right response to have to something like that. A good answer is better than a mediocre answer, and you can help instigate that change with proper reviews.

Comment: @CertainPerformance being "link-only" will fit into the "absolute" scale. If it is link-only -> should be commented as such. The essence of this particular answer is in the "inconsistency of the workspace" (in text). The link is only to demonstrates how it _might_ happen and that people have seen it. 

Could I have commented on this answer in order to try improving it? Possibly. Is this a representative example where you want to comment? Not in my opinion. Should this be an audit? Not in my opinion.

Comment: You keep defending “no action needed” was the right call for this answer. It wasn’t.

Comment: @yivi My main point is to exclude this review item from the audit lineup (that's what is in my question). That is not necessarily equivalent to the decision on whether "no action needed" is the right call.

Comment: This audit is fine to check reviewers are reviewing consistently. E.g. not picking “not action needed” when an action was needed. There is nothing wrong with this audit, IMO.

Comment: At least 58 people looked at it and nobody thought to preserve the useful information.  Its all about form and not about function anymore these days.  Fixed.

Comment: The only reason for it to be removed is if it's wrong. If it's right, but easy to make a wrong call on... It's pretty much a great audit, cause it'll catch people who aren't careful....

Answer (score 2):

At first look, it's not obvious it's an NAA -- the user makes an attempt to explain the problem and links to an issue on the Eclipse bug tracker. Granted, it's an answer, but it's definitely not a great one (you really should've downvoted it, that would've saved you). I can see why it was deleted, although I think converting it into a comment would've been more appropriate here.

This is one of those borderline cases, I don't think it should be used as a review audit.

Comment: This is the Late Answers queue, so whether it's NAA isn't really the issue, the issue is whether it's a *good* answer or not - which it isn't, like you said, so I think it is not borderline.

Comment: @CertainPerformance disagree; quality should be moderated by upvotes and downvotes, not delete votes -- those are meant for deleting answers that aren't answers at all. This was a poor answer, but an answer nonetheless.

Comment: I think it was an answer too - I'm not contesting that, I'm just contesting that "No action needed" could conceivably be the right response when presented with something like that - like you said, it's a poor answer, so it's not borderline for the Late Answers queue.

Comment: Surely there are better ways to assess review quality than auditing, e.g. time taken, level of match with other reviewers. Audit seems to me to be a very blunt tool.

Comment: Having said which I would always approach a Late Answer (specifically) as guilty until proven innocent, as most of them seem just reputation harvesting.

Comment: @MandyShaw Totally agree, with "reputation harvesting" when it (poor late answer) is done on a highly-popular post! This was not the case, here, as I specifically opened the question (1 vote) and two very short, even less informative (than the deleted-audited) answers (0 votes).