# Failed Audit by Flagging a Question on Hold

Tags: bug, review-queues, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I'm not sure I understand this particular audit review. I failed an audit by flagging it as primarily opinion based. Before selecting an audit action, I opened the question in a new tab to see that it was "put on hold" as "primarily opinion based". I read through the question and agreed with the other users' flag of the question denoting that it was primarily opinion based. [Link to Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/23773930)

The question was asking for a coding preference, where there wasn't an incorrect answer. Since it was flagged within the last day and the question was from mid-July, it seems that the review audit rotation still had it as a valid question despite being flagged. According to the review audit, the correct answer was to mark it as "looks good."

Maybe the review audit rotation doesn't update quick enough to prevent something like this from occurring? Was the question still a good question even though it had been flagged as put on hold? Did I do the right thing by flagging the question during the review audit (if so, why did I fail?)?

I've seen that there are tons of questions on Meta regarding failed audits. I have searched and don't think this is a duplicate, but here are some related questions:

- [Broken review audits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251145/555599)
- [How are review audit posts selected?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/189000/555599)
- [Who audits the audit?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/182625/555599)
- [Failed audit by commenting on it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/261656/555599)
- [Adding an I don't understand option](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188790/555599)

#### Regarding Duplicate

As for the last question ([I do not understand why I failed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303795/i-do-not-understand-why-i-failed-this-audit)), this is a different case. The post's largest upvoted answer says:

> After all, the audit system won't use a closed question as a "good
>   post" audit.

I'm saying that this exact thing happened to me, which is contrary to expected behavior. In essence, I flagged a question that was already flagged by other users and still failed the audit. It's been confirmed by the moderators that I did the right thing (in the comments below). Thus, it seems this is a unexpected behavior (eg: a bug) due to the triage queue using a cache of questions for auditing that may not always be updated, which is different from the other post.

Comment: Wait the question is on hold, you flagged it unsalvagable, and *failed?!*

Comment: Yes. Is that on me?

Comment: Probably the 9 upvotes and **0 downvote** messed up the audit system...

Comment: Does the review system take closure alone  into account?

Comment: @technogeek1995 I don't think so, unsalvageable was absolutely right IMO

Comment: I unbanned you - I don't have time to investigate the timeframe of the audit vs the closure - your review response was ok.

Comment: Should I delete this meta question or keep it alive?

Comment: @technogeek1995 Keep it alive, bugs need fixed or at least the situation explained

Comment: up to you - may as well delete it

Comment: @YvetteColomb from the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57060560/timeline) it was closed ~4hours prior to audit

Comment: @SurajRao probably caching then

Comment: At least in the close vote queue, if an audit is invalidated (for example from a close vote on the post), then the review immediately becomes unreviewable, I would expect that to mean it wasn't caching (at least not in the same way), maybe triage works differently though

Comment: This one has been used as an audit [quite a few times](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57060560/timeline). All those users either passing or failing the audit may deserve a second look...

Comment: I do not think, that this is a very clear case for either side; this question will always be a bad audit candidate. It is not even very clear "primarily opinion based" either; Remember: The user is _asking_ if he _may_ use "finally" in this case or if it is a clear abuse of this mechanism.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I do not understand why I failed this audit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303795/i-do-not-understand-why-i-failed-this-audit)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you and Yvette both suggest, the problem here is [caching](https://shouldiblamecaching.com).

The posts used to generate audits for the Triage, Close and Reopen queues are expensive to query. To avoid huge delays (and excessive db load) when generating an audit, the system queries *all* eligible posts and then caches the results, pulling IDs from the cache on future requests until the cached list is exhausted; only then are results refreshed.

Normally, this works pretty well - the criteria are *pretty strict* for known-good audits, particularly in Triage: to make the list, a question will have been already interacted with by multiple people who *could* have voted to close it but did not. It also needs to have a reasonable score, can't *ever* have been downvoted (even if the vote was later retracted) and have been on the site for between 10 and 30 days without being migrated in or bountied.

To give you an idea of just how strict those criteria are: as I type this, there are precisely 204 questions on Stack Overflow that qualify for use as known-good audits in Triage. Even if I were to look back an additional two months, the total would remain under 1000. [We put a lot of work into these criteria](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196949/request-for-review-close-reopen-known-good-audits) and they're *generally* pretty solid...

However... Nothing actually *prevents* a question from being closed between the time when its ID is cached and when it is used. And, sooner or later that happens. It happened to you, and it's happened 13 other times in the history of Triage review (out of a total of 213,028 "known-good" audits).

So I'm leaving this marked as a bug, because it is. An extremely rare one, but a bug none the less.

Comment: When you are retrieving the ID from the cache, are you not checking its state before delivering the result to the end user? That pre-check does not require a lot resources.

Comment: could you recommend course of action for those who fail such "invalid cache" audits? Do they escalate to meta, or maybe flag for moderators, "I failed audit because of known bug, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/389106"? Or maybe something else?