# Failed audit with Opinion based question classified as "high quality"

Tags: discussion

I thought that questions asking for opinions are undesired in SO and even there is a flag for those.

Just today I got a question like this ([link to audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/28162361)) and as I downvoted it, got a warning that this would be a high quality post?

> *STOP! Look and Listen.
>
> This was an audit, designed to see if you were paying attention. You didn't pass. Your review was inappropriate. This was a high quality post and you should have considered leaving it as-is or even upvoting.
> Don't worry, we've already handled this post appropriately – but please take a minute to look it over closely, keeping in mind the guidance above.*
>
> Question
>
> *Our system has identified this post as possible spam; please
> review carefully*.
>
> **Why do Calculus of Construction based languages use
> Setoids so much?** (11 votes).
> One finds that Setoids are widely used in
> languages such as Agda, Coq, ... Indeed languages such as Lean have
> argued that they could help avoid "Setoid Hell". What is the reason
> for using Setoids in the first place? Does the move to extensional
> type theories based on HoTT (such as cubical Agda) reduce the need for
> Setoids?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I do not understand why I failed this audit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303795/i-do-not-understand-why-i-failed-this-audit)

Comment: Looks like [this is the question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65493694/2821954). As of now, there are no downvotes nor close votes, so the system automatically assumed it is "high quality". The tags seem unfamiliar to me, not sure what to do without knowing more about them.

Comment: Im not a domain expert, but this question doesn't exactly seem to ask for opinions. Could you elaborate why you think it is asking for opinions?

Comment: "What is the reason for using Setoids in the first place?"   This is IMHO clearly asking for opinions, no?

Comment: Only if the there is no technical reason for doing it. But the answers seem to confirm that there is a technical/mathematical explanation for it. Not every why question is opinion based. If a question can be answered with facts instead of personal opinions, it's not opinion based.

Comment: "Why" questions are rarely opinion-based. When they're off-topic, it's because they're asking for an off-site reference such as a statement from a language designer about why a decision was made. When no such document exists, the question may be off-topic because the answers are a list of possibilities rather than a single definitive answer.