# Is this question really not close worthy?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I just started doing reviews in the Close Vote queue. Yesterday I failed [this audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/30491271) as I considered the question as needing more focus. I understand that the system chose it as an audit because it's  seen as a good question, having garnered a score of 8.

So I'd like to ask, is this question close worthy or is there something I missed which makes it good quality?

Comment: It seems a bit like it might belong on [puzzling.se] but I don't think it's inherently off-topic here. It's asking for how to solve a particular problem which is algorithmic in nature.

Comment: The question is... strange. While the question is tagged with [tag:algorithm], it only asked for the solutions. Out of the 3 existing answers, only 1 attempted to explain the approach, while the other 2 (including OP's self-answer) only showed the solutions, implying that it's trial-and-error (or brute force). While the question provided a detailed description of the issue and possibly also had a nice presentation, I'd argue that it's currently off-topic or otherwise very borderline.

Comment: The question is not related to programming at all. Neither the question nor the answers are using a programming approach to solve the problem. The question is totally off-topic on SO.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I do not understand why I failed this audit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303795/i-do-not-understand-why-i-failed-this-audit)

Comment: @gnat No. I know why the system chose this question to be considered good. And I'm also aware that the system is sometimes wrong. However, there's also the possibility that _I_ might be wrong. So I asked to make sure that _for this specific question_ it is not me that's wrong.

Comment: Is it similar to [the famous *find Waldo* question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8479058/)? (Ignoring that the [Mathematica site was launched about a month later](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1/).)

Comment: SO has the habit of interpreting programming as "the lexical knowledge of various languages/frameworks". In this sense, the question is really not about programming, but this interpretation of programming significantly deviates from the common sense.

Comment: fair enough (retracted my vote). If your question explicitly referred [proposed duplicate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303795/i-do-not-understand-why-i-failed-this-audit) in the explanation it would be easier for me to avoid this mistaken dupe vote

Comment: I probably would have voted to close it, but there's a good chance that would be an error. GET THIS OFF THE AUDIT QUEUE. It's blatantly unfair.

Comment: As one of the answerers, I totally agree that the question is currently off-topic, but the pre-edited question was more borderline. I expected the question was indirectly asking about maze-algorithms and pathfinding. My answer is admittedly rather poor; I was in the process of adding code, but unfortunately I moved on after seeing a number of edits had added a 'scoring function' and high-score list to the question. I considered commenting that the question had become a puzzling competition, but by then the post was several days old and had a positive reception (+3 or +4).

Comment: The question has been closed.

Comment: Agreed. When I started this question, the intention was on-topic but then it became something else. Thanks to @VLAZ for the recommendation to try Puzzling; wasn't aware of that one.

Comment: @KorganRivera Since you have an objective scoring formula, this *might* be on topic at [CodeGolf.SE]. But don't hold me to that. Look into their rules and norms more.

Comment: @jpmc26 Appreciate the heads up. I'll check it out. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you should have suggested to the poster to rephrase their question as "What do I need to do in order to be a programmer out in a tiled garden" ? :-P

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Generally speaking:

- Questions that are complete challenges, programming puzzles and similar are only on-topic if they are about a *specific programming problem* the OP is having while trying to solve some programming challenge. If the question is a programming challenge asking for complete solutions, it is too broad and off-topic - it might be on-topic on https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/ or https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/.
- Questions about puzzles that are *not* programming related what-so-ever, are blatantly off-topic. Again, they might be ok to post at https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/.
- Questions about algorithm theory are ok as long as the OP is expecting a similar theoretical answer and not a complete implementation ("give me the code"), which would make it too broad. However, theoretical algorithm questions are much better suited for https://cs.stackexchange.com/.

This particular question is blatantly off-topic since it is not about programming and there is no specific programming problem to solve. The correct way to moderate this is to close vote -> off topic, custom reason: *"I'm voting to close this since the question is not about programming"*.

The audit was horrible and the reason why is that the audit system has been broken for many years.

Comment: The fact [Softwareengineering.se] is missing from this answer is disturbing.

Comment: @jpmc26: 1. Maybe because that garden tiles question in no way fits on the the [SW Eng. SX](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/)? 2. If you really feel like it, you can edit it in as another option.

Comment: @jpmc26 Not at all. That site has been broken beyond repair for a long time due to wildly different expectations between every single user of the site regarding what's on-topic there. I wouldn't recommend to use that site.

Answer (score 2):

Your review was correct, it was just a bad audit. The question is off-topic (because it's not really about programming; the OP indicates that they intend to write code to solve it but have not yet done so, and they aren't really asking about that) and too broad (because the OP is asking for complete solutions to the problem rather than asking a specific, focused question).