# Is this question asking for code a good one?

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

I failed a [Close Votes audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/10857485) on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34608486/android-customized-barometer-with-its-needle

I voted to close this question as Too Broad, because it's essentially "Can you write this code for me?"

It seems to have attracted a lot of positive attention, and was picked up as an audit question. I stand by my vote; I don't think this is a good question. However, it **does** have a very high-quality answer.

Am I off base here?

Comment: IMO all [Just send me ur codez](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34739655/2564301) questions ought to be closed and deleted as quickly as database access allows.

Comment: @Jongware Yes, and im a little shocked it got 7 upvotes and that OP believes it will "Help so many developers in the future" no, just no.

Comment: The only reason it has a high quality answer is because of the bounty. Downvoted & flagged the question.

Comment: @Cerbrus I think (and hope) that the meta effect will kill off this question quickly.

Comment: @gnat: No. This question isn't about whether or not the question should be in an audit.

Comment: @Cerbrus "upvotes comes to this question lately when OP add bounty regardless the question's quality... So just down-vote and close the question is the only way to get rid of this type of review audits right now..." ([answer fully applies here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/300580/839601))

Comment: @gnat: Just because the answer also applies to this question, doesn't make the _question_ a duplicate. Besides, that answer is about audits, as well, which is irrelevant here.

Comment: @Cerbrus reread the question here, re-check the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/review/close/10857485) it refers, and take a look at tags. This question _is_ about audits

Comment: The answer has received the bounty award, and the question is currently at `-10`, closed, and with 2 delete votes...

Comment: @Cerbrus It has now been locked by a Moderator.

Comment: And unlocked again.

Comment: Why'd it get unlocked?

Comment: Apparently, the moderator changed his mind. @NateBarbettini: "Locked" isn't the same as "Closed", by the way.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is a "Gimme the codez" type question. Sadly it is upvoted and even has a Bounty on it. I do not believe that this will be of any use to future visitors or the community at large. I can't vote to close yet, but if I could, I would vote to close this question as "too broad" and downvote it accordingly.

> Am I off base here?

I fully agree with your assesment. Questions like these are regularly and justifiably closed on SO.

Whats specially insulting in my opinion is the reason he gave for placing a bounty:

> This question will clear so many logics of all developers in future.

Which is entirely false.

Comment: Yeah well why get insulted, I had a good laugh about it :) Either its a poor attempt to prevent the question being deleted when you know it should be, or this person really believes that dozens of people will be creating barometers.

Comment: @Gimby, [this is why](https://xkcd.com/386/) you should feel insulted ;-)

Comment: @Gimby Its insulting my intelligence. Nobody is fooled by this poorly veiled attempt to avoid downvotes/closure by an OP who simply wants to have his work done for him for free.

Comment: @Magisch Shut up and take my upvote. But deep down I so hope this person actually really does believe that many people will be needing barometers. That would just make my day when there actually is no ill intent behind it.

Comment: I don't know, I try to have my logics cleared every 3,000 miles or so...

Answer (score 5):

Two questions pop to my mind.

1) will this be useful to others?

That's a maybe for me. Usually with "gimme the codez" questions, both the question and the answer are pretty much irrelevant the moment the green checkmark is dished out. This answer however certainly demonstrates way more than only building a barometer, it shows some Android programming trickery that can benefit other requirements and application designs/widgets as well - with some rudimentary pointers and explanation.

2) will people be able to find this question and answer to find the relevant tips & tricks within it to solve their own non-barometer problems?

No, not a chance and certainly not in the current state of lack of text and explanation.

That would be my reasoning for agreeing that the close vote is still the way to go.

Comment: So in this case, OP can say 'thank you' – or, given that all he needs to do is copy Konstantin's (admittedly pretty awesome looking) code, just leave it as it is – and later on this question will be closed and possibly deleted. Perhaps one should warn the answerer that all of his neat work may have been for one person only.

Comment: @jongware that's the risk you take as an answerer when you choose to answer something for which you can know that it is going to be a hard one to salvage I guess. But lets not ignore the broken ruke in the answer: the meat of the code is off-site in git. But that also means it won't necessarily get lost when the question gets pruned.

Answer (score 4):

I believe, I need to explain my motivation answering this question.

I totally understand that this is "Gimme the codez" type of question. However, I simply found it ***INTERESTING*** for myself to write something similar (i.e. to challenge myself) and shared my findings. I think it might be relevant at some point for someone (even for myself). I do not think it hurts anyone here or do SO worse place to be at any level.

As it's far away from production quality, it's not deserved to be part of my github yet. But I might improve it at some point and upload it there too.

I can just **appologize**, if writing my findings as a answer was inappropriate.

And thanks for the kind words regarding the answer itself (outside the question if it was inappropriate to post it in the first place) :-)

*Upd1:*
Just to make it clear, I learnt my lesson and will avoid answering such sort of question in the future.

Comment: Its a nice answer, but unfortunately to an completly off topic question.

Comment: That said, SO is not a place to share your "Interesting findings".

Comment: I do agree with @Magisch regarding the fact, that it's offtopic question and probably doesn't deserve to be answered (but again, it's just my good will - nothing more) and do not agree with Cerbrus. SO _is_ a place where you can share your interesting findings. And then someone else can re-use it.

Comment: SO's primary focus is good Q/A. If you found something interesting, write a good question about it, or answer a good question. Don't answer a question that's bound to be deleted just because you found a decent answer. Especially if the question is a code request.

Comment: _"SO is a place where you can share your interesting findings."_ No, it isn't. And by answering an off-topic question, you've encouraged more to be posted. Please don't do that. You can share interesting findings on your blog if you like.

Comment: (And it _is_ a great answer)

Comment: Why the need for this defensive answer I wonder (yes, it is. Just look at the use of bold and uppercase)? The thing under scrutiny is the question and only the question.

Comment: Yeah - the downvotes on Konstantin's answer ("This answer is not useful") are really unfair. The only thing keeping me from upvoting is that it indicates "this answer is useful". As far as Stack Overflow is concerned, it's only useful for the OP. (Although please **do** keep this code around somewhere. I might want to find a use for it!)

Comment: @Gimby well, the answer also keeps getting unhealthy up/down-voting and I strongly doubt that it's comming from other Android-devs :-)) So I wanted to explain my motivation behind it. And to confirm, that I understood my mistake  and will try to avoid it in the future.

Comment: Am sure that a programmer of your calibre would certainly be able to share interesting bits (and help add to the collective knowledge) on questions that **deserve** your effort. This particular question was *undeserving* of that *great* answer at best.

Comment: Sometimes it's possible to salvage a bad question into a question that does deserve an answer. But a blatant "Gimme the codez" question generally doesn't fall into that category, since they tend to come from people who want others to do their work for them, for free. Sure, _some_ of the people who make blatant code requests are genuinely interested in learning, but they need to demonstrate that fact by **posting their own honest attempt at coding the answer**. If they can't do that, then please _don't_ encourage them by giving them code: feeding parasites does _not_ make SO a better place.

Comment: @KonstantinLoginov that's fair enough; the meta effect can suck. You can't really stop people from trying to punish answers to poor questions, even [if it is discouraged](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255459/is-it-okay-to-downvote-answers-to-bad-questions).